# How to hide parent div if first child is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide class "aa" if the first div element is empty in class "ca". Please guide me

My sample code:

```
<div class="aa">
<div class="ca">
   <div></div>
   <div class="cb"></div>
   <div class="cc"></div>
</div>
<div>
```

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `children(":first")` to get first child of div as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.ca').children(":first").text() == ""){
  $('.aa').hide();
}
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.ca').children(":first").text() == ""){
  $('.aa').hide();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
<div class="ca">
   <div></div>
   <div class="cb">A</div>
   <div class="cc">B</div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Extra: Might like to add a `.trim()` in there, depending on your definition of "empty" (how your html is laid out)

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the first **childNode** of the `.ca` parent element has content, and then target `.aa` from there if it does not:

```
//If there is no content within the first div of the class="ca" div...
//choose between textContent and innerHTML below 
//based on whether it is going to have any text or some HTML within (with possibly no text)
if (!document.querySelector('.ca').childNodes[0].innerHTML) {
    //hide the class="aa" div
    document.querySelector('.aa').style.display = 'none';
}
```